# find best match numeric sequence in sequence array

Tags: algorithm, math, dynamic-programming, graph-algorithm

Assume I have these two arrays:

```
float arr[] = {40.4357,40.6135,40.2477,40.2864,39.3449,39.8901,40.103,39.9959,39.7863,39.9102,39.2652,39.2688,39.5147,38.2246,38.5376,38.4512,38.9951,39.0999,39.3057,38.53,38.2761,38.1722,37.8816,37.6521,37.8306,38.0853,37.9644,38.0626,38.0567,38.3518,38.4044,38.3553,38.4978,38.3768,38.2058,38.3175,38.3123,38.262,38.0093,38.3685,38.0111,38.4539,38.8122,39.1413,38.9409,39.2043,39.3538,39.4123,39.3628,39.2825,39.1898,39.0431,39.0634,38.5993,38.252,37.3793,36.6334,36.4009,35.2822,34.4262,34.2119,34.1552,34.3325,33.9626,33.2661,32.3819,35.1959,36.7602,37.9039,37.8103,37.5832,37.9718,38.3111,38.9323,38.6763,39.1163,38.8469,39.805,40.2627,40.3689,40.4064,40.0558,40.815,41.0234,41.0128,41.0296,41.0927,40.7046,40.6775,40.2711,40.1283,39.7518,40.0145,40.0394,39.8461,39.6317,39.5548,39.1996,38.9861,38.8507,38.8603,38.483,38.4711,38.4214,38.4286,38.5766,38.7532,38.7905,38.6029,38.4635,38.1403,36.6844,36.616,36.4053,34.7934,34.0226,33.0505,33.4978,34.6106,35.284,35.7535,35.3541,35.5481,35.4086,35.7096,36.0526,36.1222,35.9408,36.1007,36.7952,36.99,37.1024,37.0993,37.3144,36.6951,37.1213,38.0026,38.1266,39.2538,38.8963,39.0158,38.6235,38.7908,38.6041,38.4489,38.3207,37.7398,38.5304,38.925,38.7249,38.9221,39.1704,39.5113,40.0613,39.3602,39.8689,39.973,40.0524,40.0025,40.7584,40.9714,40.9106,40.9685,40.6554,39.7314,39.0044,38.7183,38.5163,38.6101,38.2004,38.7606,38.7532,37.8903,37.8403,38.5368,39.0462,38.8279,39.0748,39.2907,38.5447,38.423,38.5624,38.476,38.5784,39.0905,39.379,39.4739,39.5774,40.7036,40.3044,39.6162,39.9967,40.0562,39.3426,38.666,38.7561,39.2823,38.8548,37.6214,37.8188,38.1086,38.3619,38.5472,38.1357,38.1422,37.95,37.1837,37.4636,36.8852,37.1617,37.5051,37.7724,38.0879,37.7197,38.0422,37.8551,38.5688,38.8388};
float pattern[] = {38.6434,38.1409,37.3391,37.5457,37.7487,37.7499,37.6121,37.4789,37.5821,37.6541,38.0365,37.7907,37.9932,37.9945,37.7032,37.3556,37.6359,37.5412,37.5296,37.8829,38.3797,38.4452,39.0929,39.1233,39.3014,39.0317,38.903,38.8221,39.045,38.6944,39.0699,39.0978,38.9877,38.8123,38.7491,38.5888,38.7875,38.2086,37.7484,37.3961,36.8663,36.2607,35.8838,35.3297,35.5574,35.7239};
```

Ives uploaded this example graph:
[image]

As you can see in the graph pattern almost fits in the array at index 17

Whats the best and fastest way to find this index? And is there a way to have a confidence for there match fuse the values are not equal as you can see?

Comment: What is your measure of "distance" between patters? rms, mahal, euclidean distance, or something else?

Comment: [This](http://nicoschertler.wordpress.com/2014/06/13/matching-error-prone-sequences-of-numbers-e-g-time-codes-to-each-other/) might give you an idea, though it's not exactly what you need. You probably don't need the shift approximation and therefore only one pass.

Comment: What are the constraints? Can there be gaps in the pattern, or do you just have to find the optimal start index?

Comment: Nico can you upload your code from the article? the microsoft drive says the file is missing.

Answer (score 1):

If the starting index is your only degree of freedom, you can just try each index and calculate the sum of squared errors for each of the data points. In Python this could look like this:

```py
data = [40.4357,40.6135,40.2477,...]
pattern = [38.6434,38.1409,37.3391,37.5457,37.7487,...]

best_ind, best_err = 0, 1e9999
for i in range(len(data) - len(pattern)):
    subdata = data[i : i + len(pattern)]
    err = sum((d-p)**2 for (d, p) in zip(subdata, pattern))
    if err < best_err:
        best_ind, best_err = i, err
```

Result:

```py
>>> print best_ind, best_err
17 21.27929269
```

Comment: If there are more degrees of freedom, e.g. if there can be 'gaps' when matching the pattern to the data, you could use a variant of [Minimum Edit Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), using the squared error instead of fixed cost for substitution.

Comment: @user3794234 So, did this work out for you, or is there anything else?

Comment: these algorithm make a match only if the data is 1:1 in cell but what if theres a shift in data or pattern but still you can see they match I've uploaded an example graph: http://screencast.com/t/CZ3y1jvsB72

Comment: @user3794234 Not sure what you mean. Wouldn't that fit better if you shift the pattern a bit more to the right? Not sure, but maybe that minimum edit distance extension could help. Please extend your question with more examples and detailed  description of what you really need and what not.

Comment: the above solution compares the pattern and the data as if their sequences are in the same size, as you can see in the new graph that i added there can be an offset of the data and also they won't be in the same sizes Niko Schertler solution for the offset and readings with no matching look Good but the code is missing.

Comment: @user3794234 The sequences do not have to be the same size and the pattern can of course have an offset. Did you try my solution? In case I did not understand what you want, please make your question clearer.

Comment: @N.T There's a link to the code at the end of the article.

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward algorithm is to chose a measure of convergence ( how you describe similarity, this might be average of errors, or their squared values or any other function suitable for your purposes) and apply steps

1. Let **i = 0** be an integer index, **M** be a container of **size = length(data) - length(pattern) + 1** to store the measurings
2. If **i < size** then shift your pattern by **i**, otherwise go to step 5
3. Calculate the measure of similarity and store into **M**
4. **i = i + 1**, go to 2 and repeat
5. Chose the index of minimum value in **M**

Answer (score 0):

It's a one-liner in Python, using the fact that tuples are sorted lexicographically:

```
In [1]:

import numpy as np
arr = np.array( [ 40.4357,40.6135,40.2477,40.2864,39.3449,39.8901,40.103,39.9959,39.7863,39.9102,39.2652,39.2688,39.5147,38.2246,38.5376,38.4512,38.9951,39.0999,39.3057,38.53,38.2761,38.1722,37.8816,37.6521,37.8306,38.0853,37.9644,38.0626,38.0567,38.3518,38.4044,38.3553,38.4978,38.3768,38.2058,38.3175,38.3123,38.262,38.0093,38.3685,38.0111,38.4539,38.8122,39.1413,38.9409,39.2043,39.3538,39.4123,39.3628,39.2825,39.1898,39.0431,39.0634,38.5993,38.252,37.3793,36.6334,36.4009,35.2822,34.4262,34.2119,34.1552,34.3325,33.9626,33.2661,32.3819,35.1959,36.7602,37.9039,37.8103,37.5832,37.9718,38.3111,38.9323,38.6763,39.1163,38.8469,39.805,40.2627,40.3689,40.4064,40.0558,40.815,41.0234,41.0128,41.0296,41.0927,40.7046,40.6775,40.2711,40.1283,39.7518,40.0145,40.0394,39.8461,39.6317,39.5548,39.1996,38.9861,38.8507,38.8603,38.483,38.4711,38.4214,38.4286,38.5766,38.7532,38.7905,38.6029,38.4635,38.1403,36.6844,36.616,36.4053,34.7934,34.0226,33.0505,33.4978,34.6106,35.284,35.7535,35.3541,35.5481,35.4086,35.7096,36.0526,36.1222,35.9408,36.1007,36.7952,36.99,37.1024,37.0993,37.3144,36.6951,37.1213,38.0026,38.1266,39.2538,38.8963,39.0158,38.6235,38.7908,38.6041,38.4489,38.3207,37.7398,38.5304,38.925,38.7249,38.9221,39.1704,39.5113,40.0613,39.3602,39.8689,39.973,40.0524,40.0025,40.7584,40.9714,40.9106,40.9685,40.6554,39.7314,39.0044,38.7183,38.5163,38.6101,38.2004,38.7606,38.7532,37.8903,37.8403,38.5368,39.0462,38.8279,39.0748,39.2907,38.5447,38.423,38.5624,38.476,38.5784,39.0905,39.379,39.4739,39.5774,40.7036,40.3044,39.6162,39.9967,40.0562,39.3426,38.666,38.7561,39.2823,38.8548,37.6214,37.8188,38.1086,38.3619,38.5472,38.1357,38.1422,37.95,37.1837,37.4636,36.8852,37.1617,37.5051,37.7724,38.0879,37.7197,38.0422,37.8551,38.5688,38.8388] )
pattern = np.array( [ 38.6434,38.1409,37.3391,37.5457,37.7487,37.7499,37.6121,37.4789,37.5821,37.6541,38.0365,37.7907,37.9932,37.9945,37.7032,37.3556,37.6359,37.5412,37.5296,37.8829,38.3797,38.4452,39.0929,39.1233,39.3014,39.0317,38.903,38.8221,39.045,38.6944,39.0699,39.0978,38.9877,38.8123,38.7491,38.5888,38.7875,38.2086,37.7484,37.3961,36.8663,36.2607,35.8838,35.3297,35.5574,35.7239 ] )

min( ( ( ( arr[i:i+len(pattern)] - pattern ) ** 2 ).mean(), i ) for i in xrange(len(arr)-len(pattern)) )

Out[5]:
(0.46259331934782588, 17)
```

where `0.46` is the minimal mean squared error, and 17 is the position of the minimum in `arr`.